# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to save fig to my desktop using python but showing an error how can I solve this error??
(I'm Using Windows10)

````
  File "<ipython-input-8-c928d84564a0>", line 1
    savefig("C:\Users\91800\Pictures\PythonPractise\sine.png")
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape```
````

Comment: Man this comes up a lot.  In a string a backslash designates an escape character, eg "\n" is seen as a newline.  It doesn't like the first one in your path at positions 2:3 ie "\U"  To escape the escape use two backslashes, eg "\\foo\\bar" or r"\foo\bar" or slash "/foo/bar/" IMO for paths use `Pathlib`   https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=unicodeescape